# Issue with htaccess Redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Any idea why all my redirections work EXCEPT the last one?  I've tried redirect permanent but same issue.

Many thanks,

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.mydomain.lu
Redirect 301 /biographie-/ http://www.mydomain.lu/biographie.html
Redirect 301 /personal-dsfsd/ http://www.mydomain.lu/biographie.html
```

Comment: Do you have .htaccess inside `/personal-trainer-luxembourg/` also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those all work fine for me.

One possibility is that you may have multiviews turned on, which would cause mod_negotiation to see `/personal-trainer-luxembourg/` and think you meant to go to `/personal-trainer-luxembourg.html`, and hijack the request before mod_alias can match the pattern and redirect.

Try turning off multiviews:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

additionally, make sure that you've cleared your browser's cache before testing.